# Send notification when something change in Database

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification

I want to implement logic to my xamarin.Forms application (for android and Ios), which sends notification to user when something new appears  in database. For example when other user add an invitation to database, invited user will receive it. Thanks

Comment: You want to send notification when change in database, I find one article that you can take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications, you can modify and implement logic according to this sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send out push notifications, take a look at One Signal.  It is free to use and in my experience is also the easiest to set up with Xamarin.Forms.  You would need to follow their tutorial on how to get things set up for iOS, Android, and your server side implementations.  After that when something in your DB changes just send a push notification from your server.

Here is a link to the Xamarin.Forms setup: [One Signal - Xamarin.Forms](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup)

You can also use them to notify the users via email, however I have not tried that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends completely on your underlying backend and services (REST? Websockets?, ...) and is to general to answer clearly.

For a good instruction how to use notifications in Xamarin.Android, take a look here:

[Local notifications on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications)